# c# wpf binding not working with datacontexts

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox

I wish to display a ToolTip for an entry in a Listbox.
The Toolkit will contain a Textbox and a copy (larger) of the Image in the entry in the Listbox
I can get either the Text in the Textbox Or the Image to display.
The code which displays the image but not the text is

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Border  x:Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"  Background="#EEFFFFFF" BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC"   
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            BorderThickness="1">
                        <Grid>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">                                    
                                <Image x:Name="img" ToolTipService.Placement="Top"
                                       Source="{Binding Path=ImageUri}" Height="64" Stretch="Uniform" Width="64">
                                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" x:Name="scaleTrans"/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                                    <Image.ToolTip>
                                        <ToolTip BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" Effect="{x:Null}"
                                                 DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}" 
                                                 HasDropShadow="False">
                                            <Border Background="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Width="600" 
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                                <Grid Background="{x:Null}">
                                                    <StackPanel >
                                                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Padding="5" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"
                                                               Text="{Binding Path=FTitle}"
                                                               Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveBorderBrushKey}}"/> 
                                                    <Border Margin="8,0,8,12.5"  VerticalAlignment="top">
                                                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Source}"/>
                                                    </Border>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Border> 
                                        </ToolTip>
                                    </Image.ToolTip>
                                </Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

This code is part of the code for  which is used by a ListBox
The code below (as in the list above display the Image in the tooltip but not the Textbox

```
<ToolTip BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" Effect="{x:Null}"
     DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}" 
     HasDropShadow="False">
             <Border Background="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Center"Margin="0" Width="600" 
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid Background="{x:Null}">
                   <StackPanel >
                      <TextBlock Margin="5" Padding="5" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"
                                                               Text="{Binding Path=FTitle}"
                                                               Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveBorderBrushKey}}"/> 
                     <Border Margin="8,0,8,12.5"  VerticalAlignment="top">
                          <Image Source="{Binding Path=Source}"/>
                     </Border>
                  </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
              </Border> 
           </ToolTip>
```

If you remove

```
DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}" from <ToolTip
```

The Text works as expected but the Image now fails (as expected)

I have tried to 
a) modify the original so the TextBlock binding point to the FTitle entry observable Collection driving the listbox entries

```
<TextBlock Margin="5" Padding="5" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"
        Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.FTitle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,                                               AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
        Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveBorderBrushKey}}"/>
```

b) moved the datacontext in to Image

```
<Border Margin="8,0,8,12.5"  VerticalAlignment="top">
       <Image Source="{Binding Path=DataContext.Source, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Image}}}"/>
                                                    </Border>enter code here
```

Neither worked. (I did try many variations But none worked.

I would be grateful for either solution

Answer (score 0):

`{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}` will bind the [UIElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip.placementtarget(v=vs.110).aspx) (a ListBoxItem) as the DataContext for the tooltip. It seems you want the DataContext of the ListBoxItem in order to bind to properties of the underlying model. In which case, try changing your DataContext binding to be: `{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}`